# SideKiq Unique - One Job per user_id simultaneously

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

I need to assure that no more than one job per user_id is worked simultaneosly by any of the 25 workers to avoid deadlocks.

I am trying sidekiq unique jobs but deadlocks keep occoring because it keeps trying to process all pending jobs on the queue without looking for the user_id on the params wich can't repeat at the same time on the busy line.

Any ideas how to use it? The git page is barelly documented..

```rb
SidekiqUniqueJobs.config.unique_args_enabled = true

class WordCreator   
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  sidekiq_options unique: true, unique_args: :args_filter, :queue => "critical"

  def self.args_filter(user_id)
    [user_id]   
  end

  def perform(*args)
    #retries = 100
    #begin

    work = Work.new(args.last)
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to do the same thing. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @SwaathiKyes. Yeahh. take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29212808/